# Avoiding multithreading with Java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

We're having this issue: [SLURM slow for array job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150973/slurm-slow-for-array-job/52152128)

Is there some way that

```
collection.stream().someFunction1().someFunction2() etc.
```

or

```
Arrays.stream(values).someFunction1().someFunction2() etc.
```

does cause some multithreading?

We don't have anything like "parallel" or "thread" in our code.

Thanks in advance

Martin

Comment: No.. Unless you do something like that (creating threads) within your `someFunction1` or `someFunction2`.

Comment: And what is `stream.someFunction1()` exactly? Must we suppose `map()`?

Comment: It can, if you have parallel stream.

Comment: someFunctionX are filter(), map(), findFirst(), count(), sum(), collect(), etc.
We didn't include any parallelism ourselves, and also don't have parallelStream() or similar.

Comment: And also forEach()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

From the documentation for [Collection.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream()):

> Returns a sequential `Stream` with this collection as its source.

From the documentation for [Arrays.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(T%5B%5D)):

> Returns a sequential `Stream` with the specified array as its source.

A sequential stream is the opposite of a parallel stream.  It is processed in the calling thread only.